# Database error ; the value of the foreign key is unknown

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

These are the models

```
public class theTask
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Tasks")]
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Task Status")]
    public bool TaskStatus { get; set; }

    public SubTask SubTask { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class SubTask
{
    [Key]
    public int SubTaskId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Sub Task")]
    public string SubTasks { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Sub Task Description")]
    public string SubDescription { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public bool SubStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("theTask")]
    public virtual theTask theTask { get; set; }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the modelBuilder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SubTask>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(st => st.SubTaskId);
    entity.Property(st => st.SubTasks);

    entity.HasOne(st => st.theTask)
          .WithOne(t => t.SubTask)
          .HasForeignKey<theTask>(t => t.TaskId)
          .IsRequired()
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
});
```

and this is how I coded the insertion to the database

```
public IActionResult taskCreate(TasksViewModel taskVM)
{
    theTask theTask = new theTask();
    theTask.Tasks = taskVM.Tasks;
    theTask.TaskDescription = taskVM.TaskDescription;
    theTask.TaskStatus = false;

    SubTask subTask = new SubTask();
    subTask.SubTasks = taskVM.SubTasks;
    subTask.SubDescription = taskVM.SubDescription;
    subTask.SubStatus = false;

    _db.Tasks.Add(theTask);
    _db.SubTasks.Add(subTask);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

I can't seem to understand why the foreign key is null or unknown. Without the foreign key the program seems to run just fine and my TaskId works normally but when I add the foreign key it always gets an error. I think I've encountered every error pertaining to the Foreign Key at this point lol.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property list specified using [ForeignKey("theTask")] attribute on navigation 'SubTask.theTask' is incorrect. Provide a comma-separated list of property names.'

And when I remove the `[ForeignKey("task & subtask")]`, I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The value of 'theTask.TaskId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.'

**Edit:**
I am using EntityFramework 8.0.3 and sqlserver 8.0.3 (sorry I'm kinda new to this) and I'm just using the local sql server management 19. I know I can most probably do this in sql but I'm stubbornly trying to learn the 'code first' approach.

I am genuinely confused.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ASP.NET is the **web stack** - that has nothing to do with storing data into a database. So what we really need to know is what **database access** technology are you using (Entity Framework? If yes: what exact version?), and what database are you using?

Comment: Which kind of "database" is this problem related to? The code you've shred does not look like SQL. Please adjust the tagging of your question

Comment: @marc_s I'm using EntityFramwork 8.0.3 and the 'code first' approach.

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't remember putting database in the tags, only asp.net, someone must've edited it. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you're using **Entity Framework** - possibly with a SQL Server backend - this approach might work (unfortunately, you haven't really specified the *relevant* environment info in your question...)

You're creating both your `Task` and your `SubTask` separately - without any connection between the two.

If you want to establish a foreign key relationship between them, you need to set the foreign key value for `Task` (or the `TaskId`) in your `SubTask` object, before saving.

If that `TaskId` is an identity column in SQL Server, then of course you cannot get the `Id` value before actually saving the data - but you **CAN** establish the link between the two objects, and let Entity Framework handle setting the proper `TaskId` value when saving the sub task.

Like this:

```
public IActionResult taskCreate(TasksViewModel taskVM)
{
    theTask theTask = new theTask();
    theTask.Tasks = taskVM.Tasks;
    theTask.TaskDescription = taskVM.TaskDescription;
    theTask.TaskStatus = false;

    SubTask subTask = new SubTask();
    subTask.SubTasks = taskVM.SubTasks;
    subTask.SubDescription = taskVM.SubDescription;
    subTask.SubStatus = false;
    // *NEW* - setting "theTask" on the subtask to establish link
    subTask.theTask = theTask;

    _db.Tasks.Add(theTask);
    // not really necessary - saving "theTask" will also save "subTask"
    // _db.SubTasks.Add(subTask);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```